# What test(s) to run to compare categories on a 4 point Likert scale?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likert

287 participants are asked to rate a piece of music. Each participant rated 4 pieces of music on four categories using a four-point Likert scale
This resulted in each participant giving 16 answers

I want to compare the four categories based on which score highest, which lowest, etc.

Additionally, I want to compare male participants' answers to females'
There are n = 121 male participants and n = 166 female participants.

Comment: Please indicate your four points and score for each category /point of your Likert  scale.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a) A multilevel model to deal with the repeated measures and b) Ordinal logistic regression to deal with ordinal data.  So, I'd suggest a nonlinear multilevel model.